# Count cycles in undirected graph that does not share a vertex

Tags: graph, depth-first-search, undirected-graph

I am trying to understand an algorithm to count the number of isolated cycles in a graph. By isolated, I mean the cycles that do not share any vertex. Here is an example:

[image: Example Graph]

Here, 1-2-4-1 and 3-6-5-3 are the two cycles that do not share any vertex. Hence, the algorithm must return 2. Off course, we can find all possible cycles and then figure out the isolated ones but I was wondering if there could be an alternate method for this special case.

Comment: Assume an edge between 1-3. Which cycles would you consider valid ?

Comment: Still the same. In that case 3 wont be part of the cycle 1-2-4-1 and still remains isolated from 3-6-5-3 cycle. But 1-2-4-1 and 1-4-3-1 wont be considered isolated as they share at least one vertex. Same goes for 1-4-3-1 and 3-6-5-3.

Comment: So is 1-4-3-1 an isolated cycle, making 1-2-4-1 and 3-6-5-3 and 1-2-4-3-1  non-isolated ?

Comment: Cycles are considered isolated if they do not share ANY vertex. Among the cycles 1-2-4-1, 1-4-3-1, 1-2-4-3-1,3-6-5-3, only 1-2-4-1 and 3-6-5-3 do not share vertex.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.